# How do I access a module using a string variable as a location?

Tags: python, import, path, python-import

I have a string variable x, and want to use input to call a module in a subfolder, as shown below. How can I use this string as part of the path?

```
x = input()

from subfolder.x import y
```

My code is run from a parent folder 'main.py' and uses the line:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

to set the file path.

Comment: The method in your other module could accept a parameter for the path? It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Perhaps extend your example including inputs and _desired output(s)_.

Comment: In this example, I am only trying to demonstrate importing module x. This is the relevant bit, as the rest of my code is structured to accommodate it, but I cannot get this line to run without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to dynamically import, take look at [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) consider following simple example

```
import importlib
modulename = "html"
submodulename = "entities"
what = "html5"
module = importlib.import_module(modulename + "." + submodulename)
thing = getattr(module,what)
print(thing["gt;"])  # >
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this - when I've tried it previously, I've got an error saying the package doesn't exit. Does this module only work with packages? As I am only trying to import another module in the form of a .py file.

Comment: @PublicMutiny you can use if you have .py file, remembering to NOT include *.py, for example if you have `config.py` then you might do `config = importlib.import_module("config")`

Answer (score 0):

According to Python documentation, here is how an `import` statement searches for the correct module or package to import:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:

> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default.

> After initialization, Python programs can modify `sys.path`. The directory containing the script being run is placed at the beginning of the search path, ahead of the standard library path. This means that scripts in that directory will be loaded instead of modules of the same name in the library directory.

Source: Python 2 and 3

So you can use `sys.path.append` to append a location to the path, but once you close Python, `sys.path` will be set back to default.
Or you can add the desired location permannently to `PYTHONPATH` by adding

```sh
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/my/other/path"
```

in a startup script appropriate to whatever shell you're using (`.bashrc` for bash, for example)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - how would I use this to find modules using a string variable name? As that is the problem I'm currently struggling with.